# Changing height of UITextField in default UIsearchBar

Tags: ios, swift3

I am working with the Default Search Bar and I tried to change the height of the search bar with  the following line,

```
for subView in search_bar.subviews
    {
        for subsubView in subView.subviews
        {
            if let textField = subsubView as? UITextField
            {
                textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
               // var frameRect = textField.frame;
                //frameRect.size.height = 100; // <-- Specify the height you want here.
               // textField.frame = frameRect;
                textField.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 70)
                //textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
            }
        }
    }
```

and it seems not working... can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code it works:

```
for subView in search_bar.subviews where subView is UITextField {
    subView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: subView.frame.size.width, height: 70)
}
```

Comment: @Abhinanadan what is that homeView in the above code, is it the name of search bar object??

Comment: @Three Coins but I tried it, it didn't work, if I am supposed to need to change any other thing in search bar property??

Comment: @PAVITHRANR - where you called the above code I mean viewdidload la call paniringala ila else where

Comment: @ThreeCoins in viewDidLoad only

Comment: @PAVITHRANR - try with viewwillappear or viewdidappear, you get answer

Comment: @PAVITHRANR - see this for e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30858969/can-the-height-of-the-uisearchbar-textfield-be-modified

Comment: @ThreeCoins thanks, man it works great. But why it is not working in viewDidLoad?

Comment: @PAVITHRANR - It means your UI is not updated in the current VC.

Comment: @ThreeCoins ok I got it, Thanks