# how to change height of search bar in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I have been making search bars without navigation on the imageView.
The search bar height is fixed but i want to change the search bar height.

so i tried

```
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 44)
searchbar.frame = frame
```

and

```
searchbar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
```

but they don't work.
I'm using this code

```
searchBar.isTranslucent = true
searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
```

so like this

[image]

please help me change the search bar textfield height.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the height of the UISearchbar TextField be modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30858969/can-the-height-of-the-uisearchbar-textfield-be-modified)

Comment: Using `searchbar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true` worked for me. How did you create the search bar? I added it to my storyboard with the top, leading and trailing anchors set to the superview edges. That's it, no other fancy magic.

Comment: you should customize its appearance by embedding it within a container view or modifying its superview's layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this!

```
    for myView in searchBars.subviews  {
        for mySubView in myView.subviews  {
            if let textField = mySubView as? UITextField {
                 var bounds: CGRect
            bounds = textField.frame
            bounds.size.height = 40 //(set your height)
                textField.bounds = bounds
                textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your help. but.. it doesn't work.
i modify your subsubview -> mySubView.
Actually, i don't understand subsubview .

Comment: did not work for me, too& It goes into TextField updates the frame but ob screen i get the same searchbar as before

Answer (score 3):

```
fileprivate func customizeSearchField(){
    UISearchBar.appearance().setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .normal)
    searchField.backgroundColor = .white
    if let searchTextField = searchField.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
        searchTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            searchTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            searchTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchField.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            searchTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchField.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
            searchTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchField.centerYAnchor, constant: 0)
        ])
        searchTextField.clipsToBounds = true
        searchTextField.font = GenericUtility.getOpenSansRegularFontSize(14)
        searchTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
        searchTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        searchTextField.layer.borderColor = AppColor.primaryLightGray.cgColor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found better way without hijacking objc api.

1. Make square image with desired height. In my case I've made pink square 40x40. Also I've made it with corner radius, so there is no need to specify corner radius for UITextField
2. Add image to assets
3. Specify slicing mode for you image (in my case I've also added 12pt for left and right because of corner radius. You can set left and right 1 and if you don't have corner radius)
   [image: Slicing mode in asset folder]
4. In code use `searchBar.setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "pinkbg"), for: .normal)`

Answer (score -1):

if you want to use with interface builder:

```
class MediaSearchBar: UISearchBar {
    override func layoutSubviews() {

    }
}
```

and setup it in viewDidLoad:

```
func setupSearchBar() {
    searchBar.delegate = self
    for myView in searchBar.subviews {
        for mySubView in myView.subviews {
            if let textField = mySubView as? UITextField {
                textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                    textField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.heightAnchor,
                                                      multiplier: 1.0, constant: -20.0),
                    textField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10.0),
                    textField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10.0),
                    textField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0)
                ])
                textField.clipsToBounds = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
searchBar.frame.size.height = 44
```

Comment: it didn't worked.