# swift iOS13 searchBar textfield height change

Tags: ios, swift

any chances to change `UISearchBar`'s `UITextField` height?
I tried almost all solutions which I've could found, but all are unsuccessful.

**Updated:**
I realized that ios13 searchBar doesn't contains UITextField, but contains `UISearchBarTextField` class

[image]

and here is hierarchy

[image]

as I understood we have to looking for the new class for iOS13 instead of `UITextField`

I've tried looping and search TextField

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    for subView in searchBar.subviews {
        for subsubView in subView.subviews{
            for subsubsubView in subsubView.subviews{
                if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                    if let textField = subsubsubView as? UISearchTextField{
                        var bounds: CGRect
                        bounds = textField.frame
                        bounds.size.height = 40 //(set height whatever you want)
                        textField.bounds = bounds
                        textField.layoutIfNeeded()
                    }
                } else {
                    if let textField = subsubView as? UITextField {
                        var bounds: CGRect
                        bounds = textField.frame
                        bounds.size.height = 40 //(set height whatever you want)
                        textField.bounds = bounds

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and debugger goes into condition and found UITextField and changed height, but on device - there no height changes

Comment: Have you tried looping the UISearchBar's subviews and changing the height of the UITextField (which is one of the subviews)?

Comment: In which method did you put the changes? Did you tried triggering layoutIfNeeded..?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50678045/3564632

Comment: could we apply scale transformation to textfield?

Comment: @denis_lor yup. I have tried looping and layoutIfNeed called and tried change height in willViewAppear. Nothing help

Comment: take a look into my update question

Comment: I would really love to know this as well... I also tried using searchBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true and that does not work.

Answer (score 1):

What I finally did was to set an UIImageView as a container for the UISearchBar.

Didn't work with a simple UIView, I guess it had to do with intrinsic content size?

```
    func showSearchBar() {

        self.searchNavigationItem?.setRightBarButton(nil, animated: false)


        guard let searchBar = self.searchBar else {

            assert(false, "Need a search bar to display")
            return
        }


        self.searchContainer = UIImageView()
        self.searchContainer?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let image = // Some image with the corresponding size.


        self.searchContainer?.image = image
        self.searchContainer?.alpha = 0

        self.searchContainer?.frame = // Same size as the image

        // Here you add the searchContainer into the titleView.
        self.searchNavigationItem?.titleView = self.searchContainer

        searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // Create top/bottom/leading/trailing constraints

        self.searchContainer?.addSubview(searchBar)
        searchBar.sizeToFit()

        self.searchContainer?.addConstraints([topConstraint, bottomConstraint, leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint])

         self?.searchContainer?.alpha = 1

    }
```