# Increase SearchBar TextField height in Xamarin Native iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, uisearchbar

I am having an app in which I want to increase my searchbar height.

I know it's a small thing with lots of ideas here but none of them seems to work for me in Xamarin Native iOS.

I am able to increase the height of SearchBar not the Textfield inside it.

This is my code:

```
mSearchBar.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(84.0f).Active = true;

public override void LayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.LayoutSubviews();

            mSearchBar.LayoutSubviews();
            mSearchBar.LayoutIfNeeded();

            UITextField searchTextField = (UITextField)mSearchBar.ValueForKey(new NSString("searchField"));
            searchTextField.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(84.0f).Active = true;
            
            searchTextField.LayoutSubviews();
            searchTextField.SetNeedsLayout();
            searchTextField.LayoutIfNeeded();
        }
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the height of the UISearchbar TextField? If so, you may  change it via `textField.Frame `, for more details, you can refer to [Can the height of the UISearchbar TextField be modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30858969/can-the-height-of-the-uisearchbar-textfield-be-modified#:~:text=The%20height%20of%20UISearchBar%27s%20UITextfield,UISearchBar%27s%20UITextfield%20height%20and%20backgroundImage.&text=The%20Width%20of%20the%20UIImage,it%27s%20better%20bigger%20than%2010.0%20.).