# Correct autolayout width not being returned on iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I'm trying to get the width of a `UIView` inside a custom `UITableViewCell`, in order to make some changes to it's appearance. I'm using autolayout, however, the width of the view returned is that which is defined in the xib file. This is different to its actual width once autolayout has laid out the cell.

My code is in `layoutSubviews()`:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    print(backgroundView.frame.width)
}
```

This works in iOS 9, but not in iOS 8. Calling `self.setNeedsLayout()` and `self.layoutIfNeeded()` has no effect. Where can I move the code so that it displays the correct width?

Thanks.

Comment: A quick fix could be, if the cell width is covering the full width to use `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width`, or a bit of calculation considering padding you have.

Comment: @iphonic It does have some padding but yeah this could be an option.. Just wondering if theres a better way

Comment: May be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629240/ios-autolayout-frame-size-not-set-in-viewdidlayoutsubviews) can help you.

Comment: Also if I pull to refresh then it works

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before, and if I recall correctly it had something to do with iOS not knowing the actual size until after the view has been drawn the first time.  We were able to get it to update by refreshing after viewDidAppear (like you mentioned it's the appropriate size after refreshing), but that's not exactly the nicest solution.

Something else you could try is adding constraint outlets to the cell that you manipulate wherever you do your cell setup.  For example, if you needed a UI element to be a certain width in some cases but not others, you could add a width constraint that you change the value of.  This lets your other elements resize themselves based on the other constraints in the view.  The limitation here is that you need to know the width of one of your elements beforehand.