# Child view container don't match to desired width in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview, childviews

I have a view container to show only 1 screen with phone and 2 with tab. So, in ViewDidLoad(), I use a the method

```
 func addListController(){
    self.addChildViewController(listController!)
    listController?.view.frame = defineListSize()
    self.containerView.addSubview((listController?.view)!)
    listController?.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

where the method defineListSize determine the size of the first children

```
 func defineListSize() -> CGRect {
    var rect :CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.containerView.frame.size.width, height: self.containerView.frame.size.height)

    switch (deviceIdiom) {
    case .tv:
        rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.containerView.frame.size.width/2, height: self.containerView.frame.size.height)
    case .pad:
        rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.containerView.frame.size.width/2, height: self.containerView.frame.size.height)
    case .phone:
        rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.containerView.frame.size.width, height: self.containerView.frame.size.height)
    case .unspecified: break
    default: break
    }

    return rect
}
```

However, when the first children is added on tablet, it is always widder than the half of the container view. Although, in debug, I can see that rect has the good data. I tried to use addListController() in viewWillAppear or viewWillLayoutSubviews(), but same result.
The second child view, when added on the right side, has the good dimensions, and cut the right part of the first child.

So where is the problem?
Thanks

Comment: try to call it in viewDidLayoutSubviews if there is a change

Comment: as said on the last of the message, already done, but no change

Comment: you said you have tried will layout not did layout

Comment: but might be you have encountered a very same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629240/ios-autolayout-frame-size-not-set-in-viewdidlayoutsubviews

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read well. I've just tried and it works. Thank you a lot